# How does soundcloud audio streaming work?

Tags: html, audio-streaming, soundcloud

I was just wondering about the technology used in Soundcloud's audio track streaming feature. Is it using HTML5 or some other method? As I definitely know that they aren't using the traditional Flash players. Any ideas ?

Comment: Further to Lee's answer below, in SoundCloud's HTML5 widget, it checks the browser for its ability to play MP3 files (which covers IE9+, Chrome, Safari - not Firefox or Opera) and if it can't, the SoundManager2 library is used to play the file via a hidden Flash file.

Comment: @nickf: You made it even more easier to comprehend !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our new embeddable players use a combination of Flash and HTML5. Depending on your environment the player will choose whatever technology grants the best listening experiences. HTML5 is great, but sometimes good ol' flash works even better.