# How can I allow people to listen to audio clips but can restrict them from downloading them?

Tags: security, audio, web-deployment

I am looking to build a service which will allow users to listen to snippets or total audio clip, but downloading them might be chargeable. So I want to restrict users from downloading my audioclips but should be able to listen them. Is this possible using some storage service or any other service/software?

Comment: Of course you can't *prevent* download, just make it harder.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to do this is to provide your own player software to play your clips, using some streaming protocol.  The player can be either web-based (e.g. [soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/)) or based around a desktop player or app (e.g. [spotify](https://www.spotify.com/)). This question explains a little about soundcloud : [How does soundcloud audio streaming work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391168/how-does-soundcloud-audio-streaming-work).